# Why isn't my CPAN distribution indexed by PAUSE?

Tags: perl, indexing, cpan

I've uploaded my [stasis](http://search.cpan.org/~dfarrell/stasis-0.04/README.pod) distribution to PAUSE, but it isn't in the [index](https://cpan.metacpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt).

I thought this was because it didn't contain a package, so I added a package declaration to the stasis [script](https://github.com/dnmfarrell/Stasis/blob/8328d34c968a7d044a0cbbfcdc1a8f27fc566f6b/stasis) in v0.04 like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
package stasis;
package main;
...
```

but it still wasn't indexed.

Is there anyway to get this distribution indexed that doesn't involve creating a boilerplate module file? (e.g. adding `lib/stasis.pm` to the distribution).

Comment: What does the email from Pause say? Maybe move the $VERSION variable into the package, too?

Comment: I only get the "upload" email from PAUSE, but not the "indexed" email. Interesting suggestion about $VERSION, I believe make is finding the version fine, as it inserts it into META.json.

Comment: Lowercase names are reserved for pragmas, and you shouldn't be claiming top-level namespaces for yourself!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe CPAN does not index scripts.

IMO your best option is to make a module that allows doing programmatically what your script does (and make the script use it).

You could put in a fake module or make it think your script is a module (I think listing it in [provides](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Meta/lib/CPAN/Meta/Spec.pm#provides) works), but I wouldn't if I were you.

Comment: Scripts on CPAN usually have their guts in a module named `App::$script_name`. [Example](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew)

Comment: @DavidFarrell only if by "did the trick" you mean cpan is now lying that there is a stasis module

Answer (score 2):

Because your `package` statement was not in a `*.pm` file.

The PAUSE indexer is [open source](https://github.com/andk/pause). It is a little complicated to unpack, but the regex for extracting a package name in a distribution is in [`PAUSE::pmfile::packages_per_pmfile`](https://github.com/andk/pause/blob/master/lib/PAUSE/pmfile.pm#L239), which is a method and a package that is meant to process `*.pm` files only.

The [`PAUSE::dist::_index_by_meta`](https://github.com/andk/pause/blob/master/lib/PAUSE/dist.pm#L867) method provides the alternate method of declaring a package through the `provides` keyword in the metafile.